# javascript arrow function ()=>() meaning?

Tags: javascript

I came across this syntax. Could any one explain what `getArg1ListInfo:()=>(object.freeze(arg1))` means

```
function foo (arg1,arg2) {
    let retval = {
        service:service
    }
    if(arg1) {
        retval.getArg1InfoHelper = () => {
            return {
                 subArg : "string",
                 getArg1ListInfo:()=>(object.freeze(arg1))
            }
        }
     }
     return retval
}
```

Comment: As I understand it, its like a for each function.

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo for *Object.freeze*?

Answer (score 3):

```
()=>(object.freeze(arg1))
```

is equivalent to

```
()=>object.freeze(arg1)
```

The brackets seem to be confusing you. They are not syntax, they are just redundant.

---

A reason one might use brackets in this way is for returning object literals. To use @Phil's example from the comments,

```
() => ({foo: 'bar'})
```

In this example, the brackets are used to avoid a syntax error. It's possible that the person who wrote your example code has come against this problem in the past, and has formed a habit.

Comment: Only really required when you want to return an object literal, eg `() => ({foo: 'bar'})`

Answer (score 1):

The `()=>()` syntax is a shorthand way of defining a single-statement function, where the result of that statement is returned as the result of the arrow function.

In the case of `getArg1ListInfo:()=>(Object.freeze(arg1))`, when `getArg1ListInfo` gets called, it will return the result of `object.freeze(arg1)`.

So for example:

```
var result = foo({},{}).getArg1InfoHelper().getArg1ListInfo()
```

Will mean that `result` contain the result of `object.freeze(arg1)`. [According to the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), this means that `result` would contain the object `arg1`.

Comment: Only if `object.freeze === Object.freeze`, which might be true, or not. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
(params) => (expression)
```

is the equivalent of

```
function (params) { return expression;}
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions